# How to properly include rewrite plugin into Express Gateway policies?

Tags: express, yaml, express-gateway

So I have installed my rewrite plugin, but when I try to add it to my `gateway.config.yml` file, I get this error: 

`Error: data.policies[8] should be string
    at Config.loadConfig (/home/lovro/SI_ExamProject/gateway/node_modules/express-gateway/lib/config/config.js:55:13)
    at forEach.type (/home/lovro/SI_ExamProject/gateway/node_modules/express-gateway/lib/config/index.js:12:48)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lovro/SI_ExamProject/gateway/node_modules/express-gateway/lib/config/index.js:12:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)`

This is how my `policies` look like:

`policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
  -
    rewrite:
      -
        condition:
          name: pathmatch
          match: /*
        action:
          rewrite: /catering/*
          redirect: 302`

I used this example from official documentation, but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should align the hyphen and the key:

```
  - rewrite:
  - condition:
      name: pathmatch
      match: /*
    action:
      rewrite: /catering/*
      redirect: 302
```